visualizations not showing up in dashboard
I am trying to code a customer churn dashboard in Jupyter. This is the code I'm using:
import panel as pn

# Define fig, area, bar, and stack for your visualizations
# Assuming these are already defined elsewhere in your code

# Assuming pivot_table is your DataFrame containing the pivot table data

# Convert pivot table DataFrame to a Panel DataFrame widget
pivot_table_widget = pn.widgets.DataFrame(pivot_table)

# Layout using Template
template = pn.template.FastListTemplate(
    title='Telco Churn Data',
    sidebar=[
        pn.pane.Markdown(
            "#### Dashboard provides a comprehensive overview of customer churn"
            " data for a telecommunications company. It presents key insights"
            " and visualizations to help stakeholders understand customer churn"
            " patterns and demographics."),
        pn.pane.PNG('telco.png', sizing_mode='scale_both'),
        pivot_table_widget
    ],
    main=[
        pn.Column(area, width=600, height=500),
        pn.Column(bar, width=600, height=500),
        pn.Column(stack, width=700, height=500)
    ]
)

# Display the dashboard
template.show()

However, this is the result that I get

As shown there is the title, the png, and the description, but no visualizations. I'm getting a mostly blank dashboard as opposed to an error message. What trouble shooting steps can I take to fix this?
